# How to convert a text like "15.90 €" into a number like "1590"?

Tags: javascript

I'm setting up an express checkout solution on shopify and I want to convert the total cart price that shopify shows the user (in text) into a number with any point, coma, space or currency. From this "15.90 €" to this "1590"

Answer (score 2):

Just replace every non-numeric character to empty character

```
var str = "15.90€"
str = str.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')
console.log(str)
```